# Cannot connect javascript to pug file in node express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to connect a pug file to a javascript file using script. However I do not see anything viewed in the console in-spite of the console.log that I have placed there.

The following is the structure of my app.js file.

```
const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

I have placed the pug file under the views directory and js file in the public/js folder.

I am able to render and view the pug file on load but it does not seem to be connected to the js file.

The following is the script tag I have added on my pug file.

```
.script(type='text/javascript', src='js/game-client.js')
```

This is the folder structure of my app with public and views being in the root directory

```
public/js/game-client.js
views/gameroom.pug
```

Please help me on how to proceed this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Look in the HTML source code in the browser: Is the script tag there?

Comment: Look at the Network tab in the browser's developer tools: Is a request made for the script? Does it get the response you expect? Is the URL being asked for correct?

Comment: `gameclient.js` !== `game-client.js`. For that matter, I don't think a file can have a hyphen in its name

Comment: File names can have hyphens in the name (and they are fine in URLs too), but that sort of typo would break it.

Comment: ah right, that's variables that can't have a name with an hyphen

Comment: Sorry I typed the wrong filename in the question. I have updated that. Also, I am able to see the script tag correctly in the html source code

Comment: Anyway, the Pug code and the routes look good to me, I think the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @JeremyThille That depends on the language :p  Lisp allows it

Comment: Yeah but Node doesn't run Lisp

Comment: `.script(type="text/javascript")` would generate `<div class="script" type="text/javascript"></div>`. There shouldn't be a period before `script`.

Comment: @Old Geezer I was finally able to figure that out! Yes that is what the issue was! Thank you so much.